# Converting mysql_query multi-table select command to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I have a couple of questions all pertaining to the same problem. I'm trying to update some of my MySQL connections/commands to PDO in order to mitigate SQL injections. I'm trying to convert this code:

```
$ulog = $_POST['driver'];
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $ulog;
$tablename_cc = "cc_".$ulog;
$tablename_db = "db_".$ulog;
$tablename_misc = "misc_".$ulog;
$tablename_cash = "cash_".$ulog;

$sql_cc = "SELECT * FROM " .$tablename_cc;
$sql_db = "SELECT * FROM " .$tablename_db;
$sql_misc = "SELECT * FROM " .$tablename_misc;
$sql_cash = "SELECT * FROM " .$tablename_cash;

$result_cc = mysql_query($sql_cc);
$result_db = mysql_query($sql_db);
$result_misc = mysql_query($sql_misc);
$result_cash = mysql_query($sql_cash);
```

To the following code:

```
$tables = array($tablename_cc, $tablename_db, $tablename_misc, $tablename_cash);

$A = count($tables);
$result = array();

try {
    $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM :table');
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $A) {
        $STH->bindParam(':table', $tables[$i]);
        $STH->execute();
        $result[$i] = $STH->fetchAll();
        $i++;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

However, I keep getting a syntax error. The error goes away if I try it in the following way, but this way is not very useful to me because it does not avoid SQL injections.

```
try {
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $A) {
        $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM ' .$tables[$i]);
        $result[$i] = $STH->fetchAll();
        $i++;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Although this last method works, from my understanding it does not help with mitigating SQL injection. And a secondary issue I'm running across is that sometimes these tables will not exist and my workaround for these issues in the old method was to do a small check:

```
$result_cc = mysql_query($sql_cc);
if(mysql_num_rows($result_cc) != 0){}
```

However, this intermediate step seems to be gone in PDO, so I still need to figure out how to check for this.

Comment: You cannot use `bindParam()` for [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) (in your case, table names). `bindParam()` is only applicable for parameters. I would seriously advise you avoid variable table names and rethink your DB schema

Comment: You should not be creating identical tables for each of your "drivers". The driver should be a column in the 4 tables. That's the problem, and the reason the concept of binding table names doesn't exist.

Comment: There is a table like that, but due to the way the data is being processed, there needs to be a table for each individual user/driver. These individual user tables are essentially intermediate steps (information inside them will get transferred out), but they're unfortunately necessary.

Comment: `bindParam` does string escaping with quotes, producing `'table'`. Tables are escaped with `\`` instead for names like `\`table\``. This limitation is [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and no alternative is provided, so you basically have to be vigilant and careful and do it yourself.